# Does this count as an app "User"?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know that when a user visits your app's canvas page e.g.

http://apps.facebook.com/YOUR_APP/

this counts them as a "User" and thus, your "User" counter increments.

But what about if a person clicks on the Facebook's Javascript SDK Login button on your website without using the canvas page? This one:

If they authorize the login and the optional extended permissions, does this still count as a "User" for the app and will the "User" counter increment for my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, any user authenticating to your application is counted as a user. I have many apps that don't have any apps.facebook.com presence but still have many active users. Note though that there are often inconsistencies and delays with the counts on facebook so the count may no be completely accurate.